# CakePHP complex find condition using 'and' , 'or' clause

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

My find query is this;

```
//here $u_id is id of the users table retrieved using session variable

$this->User->Request->find("all",array("conditions" =>array("request.status" => "friends" , 
"OR" => array("request.friend_id" => "$u_id","request.user_id" => "$u_id"))));
```

the equivalent SQL query is:-

```
SELECT `Request`.`id`, `Request`.`user_id`, `Request`.`friend_id`, `Request`.`status`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`name`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`password`, 
FROM 
`myblog`.`requests` AS `Request` JOIN `myblog`.`users` AS `User` 
ON 
(`Request`.`friend_id` = `User`.`id`) 
WHERE  
((`request`.`friend_id` = 3) OR (`request`.`user_id` = 3)) AND `request`.`status` = 'friends'
```

Whereas I want the following line after 'ON' in the above SQL query to get the desired result:

```
`Request`.`user_id` = `User`.`id` OR `Request`.`friend_id` = `User`.`id`
```

What changes should I make in the `find()` method,
or should I change my model?

My tables are:

> users(id, name, password, email)
>   requests(id, user_id(id of the users table),
>   friend_id(id of the users table), status)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the condition in your model.

```
public $belongsTo = array('User' => array('className' => 'Request',
                                          'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
                                          'conditions' => array('OR' => array('Request.user_id' => 'User.id', 'Request.friend_id' => 'User.id')
                                         ))
                         );
```

Comment: I did exactly as you told me, but this time i am getting the following after 'ON' in the sql query:-

(`Request`.`friend_id` = `User`.`id` AND ((`Request`.`user_id` = 'User.id') OR (`Request`.`friend_id` = 'User.id')))

Comment: I am making this case to my machine. In the mean while you can refer the following link: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1047/Joining-tables